# 2D array values

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, initialization, shortcut

I wanted to declare a 2D array and assign values to it, without running a for loop.

I thought I could used the following idea

```
int array[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

Which works fine to initialize the 2D array as well. But apparently my compiler doesn't like this.

```
/*
 1   8  12  20  25
 5   9  13  24  26
*/

#include <iostream.h>

int main()
{
    int arr[2][5] = {0};   // This actually initializes everything to 0.
    arr [1] [] = {1,8,12,20,25}; // Line 11
    arr [2] [] = {5,9,13,24,26};
    return 0;
}
```

> J:\CPP\Grid>bcc32.exe Grid.cpp
>
> Borland C++ 5.5.1 for Win32 Copyright (c) 1993, 2000 Borland
>
> Grid.cpp:
>
> Error E2188 Grid.cpp 11: Expression syntax in function main()
>
> Error E2188 Grid.cpp 12: Expression syntax in function main()
>
> Warning W8004 Grid.cpp 14: 'arr' is assigned a value that is never used in funct
>   ion main()
>
> *** 2 errors in Compile ***

Please help as to what is the right way to initialize the 2d array with my set of values.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Like this:

```
int main()
{
    int arr[2][5] =
    {
        {1,8,12,20,25},
        {5,9,13,24,26}
    };
}
```

This should be covered by your C++ textbook: which one are you using?

Anyway, better, consider using `std::vector` or some ready-made matrix class e.g. from Boost.

Comment: thanks. I am looking at thinking in C++ Vol1 . But I don't think it ahs a chapter for 2d arrays in specific.

Comment: Is it possible to first declare the array and then assign later?

Comment: @Ayos: yes, if you assign individual items one at a time. to assign the whole shebang you need C++11 and the array wrapped in a `struct`. so then you'd just use a `std::array`. well, trying that out, it compiles fine with g++ 4.7.2 but not (yet) with visual c++ (i used the november 2012 CTP). so wholesale assignment seems to be not yet very portable.

Comment: Unfortunately quite a few C++ textbooks don't explicitly state how to initialize 2d arrays. And those who typically only show how to using a nested for loop. I say unfortunately because this is important syntax to learn.

Answer (score 11):

The proper way to initialize a multidimensional array in C or C++ is

```
int arr[2][5] = {{1,8,12,20,25}, {5,9,13,24,26}};
```

You can use this same trick to initialize even higher-dimensional arrays if you want.

Also, be careful in your initial code - you were trying to use 1-indexed offsets into the array to initialize it.  This didn't compile, but if it did it would cause problems because C arrays are 0-indexed!

Answer (score 9):

Just want to point out you do not need to specify all dimensions of the array.

The leftmost dimension can be 'guessed' by the compiler.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
  int arr[][5] = {{1,2,3,4,5}, {5,6,7,8,9}, {6,5,4,3,2}};
  printf("sizeof arr is %d bytes\n", (int)sizeof arr);
  printf("number of elements: %d\n", (int)(sizeof arr/sizeof arr[0]));
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

`int iArray[2][2] = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};`

Think of a 2D array as an array of arrays.

Answer (score 3):

One alternative is to represent your 2D array as a 1D array.  This can make element-wise operations more efficient.  You should probably wrap it in a class that would also contain width and height.

Another alternative is to represent a 2D array as an `std::vector<std::vector<int> >`.  This will let you use STL's algorithms for array arithmetic, and the vector will also take care of memory management for you.