# C++: Creating a Two-Dimensional Array of a Struct

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, struct, int

I have a struct...

```
struct playerProbs {
int probPlayer1;
int probPlayer2;
};
```

And a 2-D array
`playerProbs killChart[11][11]=`

I am attempting to add values into the `probPlayer1` and `probPlayer2` in each struct in each position of the array. All of the values differ. I was wondering the fastest, most code efficient way to go about this?

I've looked at some examples, but they all seem very, very time consuming.
Thanks for your time!

EDIT: Current Code,

```
    struct playerProbs {
    int probPlayer1;
    int probPlayer2;
};

playerProbs killChart[11][11];

killChart[0][0].probPlayer1 = 30; //getting an error saying size of array 
killChart[0][0].probPlayer2 = 30; //must be bigger than 0
```

Comment: So you want to populate this 2d array? As you only have 121 elements (virtually nothing) just use a double nested for loop. That would be by far the easiest to code and efficiency with such a small n is irrelevant. (You already would have an O(n) efficiency).

Comment: What are you compiling this with? I just ran the "Current Code" you posted and it worked perfectly.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studios 2010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only populating a very small dataset, as such just utilize a nested for loop.

```
for(int i(0); i < 11; ++i)
    for(int j(0) j < 11; ++j)
        killChart[i][j].probPlayer1 = x;
        killChart[i][j].probPlayer2 = y;
    }
}
```

Edited per request in comments this is how you would enter these in longhand. 
To assign a give value, let us use:

```
killChart[0][0].probPlayer1 = 30;
killChart[0][0].probPlayer2 = 30;

killChart[0][1].probPlayer1 = 30;
killChart[0][1].probPlayer2 = 30;

/// ........
killChart[10][10].probPlayer1 = 30;
killChart[10][10].probPlayer2 = 30;

// And so on and so forth for all values
```

A complete code that can be run (with a much smaller sample size, only a 2x2 array) is shown below: (I don't want to type out all 121 values, and this demonstrates both methods of using it. )

```
struct playerProbs {
    int probPlayer1;
    int probPlayer2;
    playerProbs(int _v1, int _v2) : probPlayer1(_v1), probPlayer2(_v2){}
};

int main()
{


playerProbs killChart[2][2] = 
                {   // Assign via bracket initialization
                    { playerProbs(30,30), playerProbs(30,30) },
                    { playerProbs(30,30), playerProbs(30,30) },
                };

// Assign via individual initialization. 
killChart[0][0].probPlayer1 = 30;
killChart[0][0].probPlayer2 = 30;
killChart[0][1].probPlayer1 = 30;
killChart[0][1].probPlayer2 = 30;
killChart[1][0].probPlayer1 = 30;
killChart[1][0].probPlayer2 = 30;
killChart[1][1].probPlayer1 = 30;
killChart[1][1].probPlayer2 = 30;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think I misworded my question. For example `killChart[0][0]=probPlayer1.x=.3 probPlayer1.y=.3` while `killChart[0][1]=probPlayer1.x=.1 probPlayer1.y=.15` All fields in the array are different

Comment: @BeccaBohem How are you deciding on these values? If you want static values assigned at compile time, then you likely will need to code it out long-hand. Otherwise if you are using some algorithm to decide these values then you likely can find a way to have it as a function of i & j, and have the for loops assign the numbers for you. Otherwise, is there any information you can give in regards to how they are being used that will be relevant to other ways to fill their values?

Comment: I believe I'll just have to do it long-hand seeing as how theres no rhyme or reason behind the values, could you give me one example of how I'd put in the values for `killChart[0][0]` with the values `probPlayer1=30, probPlayer2=30`? I haven't coded in C++ in a long time and am havin some difficulty figuring it out

Comment: can't you use brace-initialization on multi-dimensional arrays? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4981197/2d-array-values-c)

Comment: @vu1p3n0x You absolutely can, however I think readability will be far higher in this usage. (Nested brace initialization gets REALLY messy and often takes longer to do as you constantly are losing your place.) (Especially true for having to declare the values of the struct,[you need a constructor]) In all honesty, I would probably write a script to type to type the syntax and you just enter in the values either way.

Comment: I'm still getting an error for some reason, could you check out my edit?

Comment: @BeccaBohem I just ran it with g++ 5.3 and didn't get any errors. What compiler are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to use brace-initialization

```
struct playerProbs {
    int probPlayer1;
    int probPlayer2;
};

playerProbs killChart[11][11] = {
    { {1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}, {7, 8}, ... }, // 11 { , }s
    { {4, 7}, {3, 5}, {0, 4}, {1, 6}, ... },
    ...                                      // x11
}
```

Though as Chris says may be pretty unreadable at 11x11 elements.

Comment: You have to also assign values to probPlayer1 member and probPlayer2 member. (killChart is an array of structs, not ints) You need to declare a constructor for playerProbs to assign the values.

Comment: If visual studio 2010 has proper c++11 aggregate initialization then you don't need the constructor, but I don't have faith in VS2010 for c++11