# Why is my class object causing undeclared identifier errors?

Tags: c++

I am writing a program on Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express and am having an issue with my class object. I keep getting undeclared identifier and missing ';' before identifier errors and I'm not sure what is causing the problem.

I've checked my headers for any mistakes and have made several changes to see if it would fix the problem with no luck.

```
// RightJust class declaration that right justifies the numbers.
#ifdef RIGHTJUST_H_
#define RIGHTJUST_H_
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
using namespace System;
using namespace std;
class RightJust
{
    private:
        int x, totalWH1, totalWH2, totalWH3, totalWH4;  
        int itemT1, itemT2, itemT3, itemT4, itemT5;     // Holds item totals
        string WH1, WH2, WH3, WH4;
        int num[4][5];          // Array containing data
    public:
        RightJust();
        int warehouseLen();
        void rightJustZero();
        void rightJustLess();

};
```

```
// This program asks to user to choose a report type and displays
// the report type chosen.

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "RightJust.h"
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
using namespace System;
using namespace std;

int main
{
       RightJust type;
    if(reportType == 1)
    {
        type.rightJustZero();
    }
    else if(reportType == 2)
    {
        type.rightJustLess();
    }
}
```

I just want a solution to get rid of all the error messages to see if my program is working how I needed it to work.

```
Test3.cpp
1>Test3.cpp(24): error C2065: 'RightJust' : undeclared identifier
1>Test3.cpp(24): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'type'
1>Test3.cpp(24): error C2065: 'type' : undeclared identifier
1>Test3.cpp(27): error C2065: 'type' : undeclared identifier
1>Test3.cpp(27): error C2228: left of '.rightJustZero' must have class/struct/union
1>          type is ''unknown-type''
1>Test3.cpp(31): error C2065: 'type' : undeclared identifier
1>Test3.cpp(31): error C2228: left of '.rightJustLess' must have class/struct/union
1>          type is ''unknown-type''
```

Comment: You're missing an `#endif` in the header.

Comment: _I'm not sure if this is enough of the code to find a solution to my problem_. It's enough if it reproduces your error messages.

Comment: Never put `#include "stdafx.h"` in a header.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  It might help to read [ask] and [mcve] -- MCVE explains  how you know this: *I'm not sure if this is enough of the code to find a solution to my problem*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The include guard in your header is wrong.  It should be

```
#ifndef RIGHTJUST_H_
```

Using `#ifdef RIGHTJUST_H_` will skip the code if the symbol is *not* defined.

You should not have `#include "stdafx.h"` in your .h files.  And since you seem to be using Visual Studio, you can just use `#pragma once` instead of the include guard.

Comment: I have made the changes but now I am getting an error on the 2 dimension array I have initialized in my constructor.                                                                                    
`num[4][5] ={14,15,5,0,16,15,20,25,0,5,25,25,40,30,20,5,3,10,0,10};`                                   
                                            `error C2059: syntax error : '{'`

Comment: @ymneedhelp you should ask a different question. That is completely unrelated to this. Edit this should help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4981220/487892